# Unable to deserialize parameter "jsonClass" using Json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I have a json which looks like this

```
var cutJson =
  """
    |{
    | "routingKey": "event.orders.status.paid",
    | "jsonClass" : "Event"
    |}
  """.stripMargin[enter image description here][1]
```

I aim to decerialize it and construct scala object. Here is a model of it

```
case class Order(routingKey: String, jsonClass: String)
```

Here is the line which is supposed to decerialize

```
   var myJson = read[Order](cutJson)
```

Program crashes with following error, however if I use only routingKey parameter it works perfectly fine

Here is an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u59Ea.png)

Comment: You didn't add the error nor the lib you are using to parse json...

Comment: Added error message and library name